# Add a value to a raster layer in ArcGIS

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, raster-calculator

I have various different species distribution models, whose output shows expected presence or absence as species over an area. For each species, I have a metric of vulnerability to anthropogenic activity; how do I add this value to each species so that this value appears where it is present, to be able to sum the total vulnerability scores of all species for each pixel? In QGIS I reckon field calculator could be used for this, but I’m not sure whether ArcGIS has an equivalent.

Comment: In QGIS the field calculator is for vector not raster data. Do you mean raster calculator? If so, then yes ArcGIS has a raster calculator.